# EF Core dynamically filter from list

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on creating a generic dynamic filter on a front-end table. The idea is each column will have a filter, where you can select values of that column. The column names must be completely dynamic and selected values. We are using .NET 5 and EF Core 5.

The SQL query I want is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE externalId IN ('1234', '5678');
```

Models:

```cs
public class ColumnFilter
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } // column name
        public List<string> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new List<string>(); // values selected in this column
    }

public class User {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string ExternalId { get; set; } 
}
```

Simplified code:

```cs
//columnfilter really comes from API request
var columnFilter = new ColumnFilter{
Name = "ExternalId",
SelectedValues = new List<string>{ "1234", "5678" }
};

var queryable = _context.Users.AsNoTracking();

queryable = queryable.Where(f => columnFilter.SelectedValues.Contains(EF.Property<string>(f, columnFilter.Name)));

var values = await queryable.ToListAsync(); // 0 results
```

EF Core generates this query:

```sql
      SELECT *
      FROM [Users] AS [u]
      WHERE 0 = 1
```

How do I get this to work dynamically?

Comment: I think that you should have a look at `Dynamic LINQ library`, that should fix the problem for you. Build the expression dynamicly

Comment: Is that library safe from sql injections?

Comment: You simple able to build Expression dynamicly, @Svyatoslav Danyliv solution should also be a very good solution

Answer (score 1):

It is a sample using string values:

```cs
var queryable = _context.Users.AsNoTracking();

queryable = queryable.FilterDynamic(columnFilter.Name, columnFilter.SelectedValues);
```

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string fieldName, ICollection<string> values)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName);
        var body = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] {typeof(string)},
            Expression.Constant(values), prop);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
        return query.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I had actually works. I had some other code involved that was causing the issue.