# C# Entity Framework Core Sql Server - Query fields dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I keep my question simple instead of explaining my complete situation.
Is there a possibility to build a query in Entity Framework Core by providing the query field names of the table from a variable?

Let's assume this table

Table "product"

- id bigint
- name string
- status int

The users can filter individually by choosing and combining different filters. So I have a list of filters which should be applied to the query.

So if a user wants to filter only by `id`, I need a query which looks like this, but with the `product.id` filled by a variable from my filter list (`filter.fieldName`)

```
using(Database.DBContext context = new Database.DBContext())
{
    var query = context.ProductsTable;
    foreach(Models.Filter filter in filterList)
    {
        query.Where((product) => product.id == filter.value); // <-- product.id to be replaced by variable (filter.fieldName)?
    }
    var results = query.ToList();
}
```

Or is there another way to achieve this without using `Where`. I know I could also use LINQ, but I think there is the same issue.

Comment: Does [this answer help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65674951/1048425)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dynamic SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#dynamic-sql-and-parameters) in EFCore using [`FromSqlRaw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-7.0) - **but be *very careful* when using it** - you'll have to protect yourself from possible [SQL Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver16) attacks.
`FromSqlRaw` allows you to use string interpolation to build the SQL query - so in your case it would be something like this:

```
using(Database.DBContext context = new Database.DBContext())
{
    var query = context.ProductsTable;
    foreach(Models.Filter filter in filterList)
    {
        var filterValue = new SqlParameter("filterValue ", filter.value);
        query.FromSqlRaw(
            $"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE {filter.fieldName}=@filterValue",
            filterValue); 
    }
    var results = query.ToList();
}
```

**Important**: the filter value is provided to the database via an sql parameter so it's SQL injection safe, but the column name is not safe - and you should protect yourself from SQL injection using this method.

If your `fieldName` property value comes from a closed list of options in your own code, and all the user can do is choose from it, then you're safe.
However, if the user can enter the value of `fieldName` as free text, you will have to verify that it's a valid name *before* attempting to run the query.
You do that by white-listing the value - meaning compare the entered value to the actual column name in the database (Note: The name of the property in the model isn't required by EF to be the same as the name of the column in the database).

Comment: Many thanks. This is what I need. The table field name is secure. The user has no influence to this value. Many thanks again!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the mapping layer, you can work with Entities + Expressions.

```
using(Database.DBContext context = new Database.DBContext())
{
    var query = context.ProductsTable;
    foreach(Models.Filter filter in filterList)
    {
        var lambdaParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductsTable));
        var lambdaPropertyAccessor = Expression.Property(lambdaParameter, filter.FieldName);

        var comparisonBody = Expression.Equal(lambdaPropertyAccessor, Expression.Constant(filter.Value));
        var comparisonLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ProductsTable, bool>>(comparisonBody, lambdaParameter);

        query = query.Where(comparisonLambda);
    }
    var results = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, imo. It also fixes the bug in the question itself (also copied in the other answer) by `query = query.Where(comparisonLambda);`.